# How to pass constructor values into the DOM

Tags: javascript

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/jdfill/pen/MWyNxje).

I have a form that people fill out. On clicking submit I want the data to be entered onto the page.

The empty log array and then Patient constructor:

```
// Set patient log to empty array
let myLog = [];

// Create patient constructor
function Patient(
  name,
  date,
  primInsurance,
  secInsurance,
  estimate,
  isItCovered,
  followUp
) {
  this.name = name;
  this.date = date;
  this.primInsurance = primInsurance;
  this.secInsurance = secInsurance;
  this.estimate = estimate;
  this.isItCovered = isItCovered;
  this.followUp = followUp;
}
```

When you click submit, it runs this function:

```
function addPatientToList(e) {
  // Grab elements
  const nameValue = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  const dateValue = document.querySelector("#date").value;
  const primInsurValue = document.querySelector("#primary-insurance").value;
  const secInsurValue = document.querySelector("#secondary-insurance").value;
  const estimateValue = document.querySelector("#estimate").value;
  const isItCoveredValue = document.querySelector("#covered").value;
  const followUpValue = document.querySelector("#follow-up").value;
  e.preventDefault();

  // Instantiate patient
  const patient = new Patient(
    nameValue,
    dateValue,
    primInsurValue,
    secInsurValue,
    estimateValue,
    isItCoveredValue,
    followUpValue
  );

  myLog.push(patient);
  renderPatient();
  clearFields();
  closeModal();
}
```

After adding the patient to the constructor, it attempts to render to the dom:

```
function renderPatient() {
  const list = document.querySelector("#patient-list");
  const row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.innerHTML = `
  <td>${Patient.name}</td>
  <td>${Patient.date}</td>
  <td>${Patient.primInsur}</td>
  <td>${Patient.secInsurance}</td>
  <td>${Patient.estimate}</td>
  <td>${Patient.isItCovered}</td>
  <td>${Patient.followUp}</td>`;

  list.appendChild(row);
}
```

What shows up in the dom is just 'undefined' across all table rows.

Comment: did you mean `${patient.name}` instead of `${Patient.name}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the `Patient` "class" and not the `patient` "instance", here's the code fixed.

```
const submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submit");

// Set patient log to empty array
let myLog = [];
var patient;
// Create patient constructor
function Patient(
  name,
  date,
  primInsurance,
  secInsurance,
  estimate,
  isItCovered,
  followUp
) {
  this.name = name;
  this.date = date;
  this.primInsurance = primInsurance;
  this.secInsurance = secInsurance;
  this.estimate = estimate;
  this.isItCovered = isItCovered;
  this.followUp = followUp;
}

// On click, submit patients to log and clear fields
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", addPatientToList);

function addPatientToList(e) {
  // Grab elements
  const nameValue = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  const dateValue = document.querySelector("#date").value;
  const primInsurValue = document.querySelector("#primary-insurance").value;
  const secInsurValue = document.querySelector("#secondary-insurance").value;
  const estimateValue = document.querySelector("#estimate").value;
  const isItCoveredValue = document.querySelector("#covered").value;
  const followUpValue = document.querySelector("#follow-up").value;
  e.preventDefault();

  // Instantiate patient
  patient = new Patient(
    nameValue,
    dateValue,
    primInsurValue,
    secInsurValue,
    estimateValue,
    isItCoveredValue,
    followUpValue
  );

  myLog.push(patient);
  renderPatient();
  clearFields();
  closeModal();
  console.log(myLog);
}

// Render patient to list
function renderPatient() {
  const list = document.querySelector("#patient-list");
  const row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.innerHTML = `
  <td>${patient.name}</td>
  <td>${patient.date}</td>
  <td>${patient.primInsur}</td>
  <td>${patient.secInsurance}</td>
  <td>${patient.estimate}</td>
  <td>${patient.isItCovered}</td>
  <td>${patient.followUp}</td>`;

  list.appendChild(row);
}

// Close modal
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Clear fields
function clearFields() {
  nameValue = "";
  dateValue = "";
  primInsurValue = "";
  secInsurValue = "";
  estimateValue = "";
  isItCoveredValue = "";
  followUpValue = "";
}

///// Show / hide modal

// Grab the modal / button
const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#add");
const closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

// Anywhere outside, close modal
window.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing anything when you call `Patient.property`. You could just pass the patient object to `renderPatient`.

```js
function addPatientToList(e) {
  // Grab elements
  const nameValue = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  const dateValue = document.querySelector("#date").value;
  const primInsurValue = document.querySelector("#primary-insurance").value;
  const secInsurValue = document.querySelector("#secondary-insurance").value;
  const estimateValue = document.querySelector("#estimate").value;
  const isItCoveredValue = document.querySelector("#covered").value;
  const followUpValue = document.querySelector("#follow-up").value;
  e.preventDefault();

  // Instantiate patient
  const patient = new Patient(
    nameValue,
    dateValue,
    primInsurValue,
    secInsurValue,
    estimateValue,
    isItCoveredValue,
    followUpValue
  );

  myLog.push(patient);
  renderPatient(patient);
  clearFields();
  closeModal();
  console.log(myLog);
}

// Render patient to list
function renderPatient(patient) {
  const list = document.querySelector("#patient-list");
  const row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.innerHTML = `
  <td>${patient.name}</td>
  <td>${patient.date}</td>
  <td>${patient.primInsurance}</td>
  <td>${patient.secInsurance}</td>
  <td>${patient.estimate}</td>
  <td>${patient.isItCovered}</td>
  <td>${patient.followUp}</td>`;

  list.appendChild(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is those properties aren't static properties of the `Patient` class, they are only available from the instance of `Patient`. You can access them via:

```
  // Instantiate patient
  const patient = new Patient(
    nameValue,
    dateValue,
    primInsurValue,
    secInsurValue,
    estimateValue,
    isItCoveredValue,
    followUpValue
  );

  console.log(patient.nameValue); // outputs patient name from modal
```